# Get value from registry via batch file and do comparison with other sub folder whether this value exist and do the exporting

Tags: windows, batch-file, registry

Appreciate if anyone could give some advises on how to retrieve a value from registry to do comparison with a list of subfolder. Example as below:

Path in registry:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon
```

From above path, it have 3 column with values:

```
Column [Name] : value [LastUsedUsername]
Column [Type] : value [REG_SZ]
Column [Data] : value [Administrador]
```

I want to get the value `Administrador` from column `Data`. Then with this value I need to compare with a list of subfolder, if this value exist in other subfolder, then it will export file in sub folder.

Answer (score 0):

According to your provided information, the following will save the value data from your column to a variable:

```bat
@Set "VarName="
@For /F "EOL=HTokens=2*" %%G In ('^""%__AppDir__%reg.exe" Query ^
 "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon" ^
 /V "LastUsedUsername" 2^>NUL^"')Do @Set "VarName=%%H"
@If Not Defined VarName GoTo :EOF
```

*Your code would continue on the very next line, where `%VarName%` would be used for your comparison. I am unable to provide that for you at this time, because:*

1. *This is not a free code writing service*.
2. *You have not provided sufficient details for someone to do that for you.*